# LinearLayout problem [Android]

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view, android-linearlayout

Okay, I belittle myself.  Its actually confusing me because it shows up fine on the Emulator, just not on my phone.

On the emulator, I see the custom SurfaceView _map Object take up the whole screen, except for the EditText text-box at the bottom, right where it should be. When I run the same code, same everything, on my Motorola Droid, there is no EditText to be seen anywhere.

I figure that I am missing something with the LinearLayout implementation I have.  Until now, I've gotten off easy on learning how to use another API's layout manager.

Here's the code:

```
    _map = new Map(this);
    _chatText = new EditText(this);

    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    layout.addView(_map, 0);
    layout.addView(_chatText, 1);

    setContentView(layout);
```

Looks so straitforward, so I honestly don't have a clue why it just eats my EditText when run on an actual Android device.  And sadly enough, I've already spent a sad amount of time getting it to show up correctly just in the emulator itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, you may see different results on different phones. Although the emulator may be showing the correct results, they may be different results on different devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, different phones will yield different results.  And such may have been the case for me, as I also have my phone overclocked to overclocked to 1.2ghz and have a custom rom.  Either way, the solution to this little glitch was adding a weight specification to the Views added to the layout.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpMap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); // Verbose!
    lpMap.weight = 0.15f;
```

I then used the following line instead of what I had above:

```
layout.addView(_map, 0, lpMap);
```

I hope this helps somebody.  Definitely a confusing situation, but sometimes tinkering around is the solution.  Although I answered my own question, much thanks to the community at large.